# Disable cache for plots

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to hack some way of automatically generating a pptx with figures generated via `knitr` and wanted to know if there's a way of disabling `cache` only for chunks that produce plots. I've tried to set cache to false when there's a caption like this:

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(fig.cap = function(options) {
   options$cache <- FALSE
   options
})
```

but it doesn't work (probably the `cache` option is evaluated before that).

I've also tried to set it in the `plot` hook, with no results.

```
knit_plot <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("plot")

knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options) {
   options$cache <- FALSE
   read_pptx(pptfile)  %>% 
      add_slide(layout = "figure", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
      ph_with_gg(last_plot(), type = "pic") %>% 
      print("pptprueba.pptx")
   knit_plot(x, options)
})
```

Of course I could just manually set `cache = FALSE`, but I was hoping for a more programmatically way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it turns out I had to use `opts_hooks` instead of `knit_hooks`. This works:

```
knitr::opts_hooks$set(fig.cap = function(options) {
   options$cache <- FALSE
   options
})
```